# Using itertools, melt and groupby correctly to count pairs of event per attribute value using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table on the following format

```
  Id   |   Sequence   |   Attribute A  |  Attribute B |
  ID1       [A,B,C,D]         A1              B1        
  ID2       [A,B,F,G]         A2              B3            
  ID3       [A,B,C,D]         A1              B1
```

I want to calculate, for each event combination and attribute value, count the number of unique ID's.

The final table should look like

```
  Pair    |  Attribute Type | Attribute Value   | ID Count
  (A,B)        Attribute A          A1              2        #Event A happens before event B in 2 unique ID's where A1 is the value of Attribute A.
  (A,C)        Attribute A          A1              2
  (A,D)        Attribute A          A1              2
  (B,C)        Attribute A          A1              2
  (B,D)        Attribute A          A1              2
  (C,D)        Attribute A          A1              2
  (A,B)        Attribute A          A2              1
  (A,F)        Attribute A          A2              1 
  (A,G)        Attribute A          A2              1 
  (B,F)        Attribute A          A2              1
  (B,G)        Attribute A          A2              1
  (F,G)        Attribute A          A2              1
  (A,B)        Attribute B          B1              2
  (A,C)        Attribute B          B1              2
  (A,D)        Attribute B          B1              2
  (B,C)        Attribute B          B1              2
  (B,D)        Attribute B          B1              2
  (C,D)        Attribute B          B1              2
  (A,B)        Attribute B          B3              1
  (A,F)        Attribute B          B3              1 
  (A,G)        Attribute B          B3              1 
  (B,F)        Attribute B          B3              1
  (B,G)        Attribute B          B3              1
  (F,G)        Attribute B          B3              1
```

What would be the correct way of doing this? In reality I will have more than just 2 Attributes.

This is how far I have come

```
 df['Sequence Combs'] = df['Sequence'].apply(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x,2)))
 

  Id   |   Sequence   |          Event Combs                   |   Attribute A  |  Attribute B |
  ID1       [A,B,C,D]   [(A,B),(A,C),(A,D),(B,C),(B,D),(C,D)]           A1              B1        
  ID2       [A,B,F,G]   [(A,B),(A,F),(A,G),(B,F),(B,G),(F,G)]           A2              B3              
  ID3       [A,B,C,D]   [(A,B),(A,C),(A,D),(B,C),(B,D),(C,D)]           A1              B1
```

And after doing explode

```
df = df.explode('Sequence Combs')
```

I get the following

```
  Id   |   Sequence   |  Event Combs |  Attribute A  |  Attribute B |
  ID1       [A,B,C,D]       (A,B)           A1              B1        
  ID1       [A,B,C,D]       (A,C)           A1              B1        
  ID1       [A,B,C,D]       (A,D)           A1              B1        
  ID1       [A,B,C,D]       (B,C)           A1              B1        
  ID1       [A,B,C,D]       (B,D)           A1              B1        
  ID1       [A,B,C,D]       (C,D)           A1              B1        
  ...          ...           ..             ..              ..
```

But I am unsure on how to proceed from here, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
from itertools import combinations

# create function for creating a list the 2-combinations
combs = lambda x: list(combinations(x, r=2))

# create new DataFrame with now the Sequence column is the list of the 2-combinations
res = df.assign(seq=df['Sequence'].apply(combs)).drop('Sequence', axis=1).rename(columns={'seq' : 'Sequence'})

# explode, then melt
res = res.explode('Sequence').melt(id_vars=['Id', 'Sequence'], var_name='Attribute Type', value_name='Attribute Value')

# finally group by all the columns but Id, and count
res = res.groupby(['Sequence', 'Attribute Type', 'Attribute Value'])['Id'].count()

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
Sequence  Attribute Type  Attribute Value
(A, B)    Attribute A     A1                 2
                          A2                 1
          Attribute B     B1                 2
                          B3                 1
(A, C)    Attribute A     A1                 2
          Attribute B     B1                 2
(A, D)    Attribute A     A1                 2
          Attribute B     B1                 2
(A, F)    Attribute A     A2                 1
          Attribute B     B3                 1
(A, G)    Attribute A     A2                 1
          Attribute B     B3                 1
(B, C)    Attribute A     A1                 2
          Attribute B     B1                 2
(B, D)    Attribute A     A1                 2
          Attribute B     B1                 2
(B, F)    Attribute A     A2                 1
          Attribute B     B3                 1
(B, G)    Attribute A     A2                 1
          Attribute B     B3                 1
(C, D)    Attribute A     A1                 2
          Attribute B     B1                 2
(F, G)    Attribute A     A2                 1
          Attribute B     B3                 1
Name: Id, dtype: int64
```

If you want to **truly** match the expected output, do:

```
# finally group by all the columns but Id, and count
res = res.groupby(['Sequence', 'Attribute Type', 'Attribute Value'], as_index=False)['Id'].count().rename({'Id' : 'Id Count'}).sort_values('Attribute Type')

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   Sequence Attribute Type Attribute Value  Id
0    (A, B)    Attribute A              A1   2
1    (A, B)    Attribute A              A2   1
20   (C, D)    Attribute A              A1   2
4    (A, C)    Attribute A              A1   2
6    (A, D)    Attribute A              A1   2
18   (B, G)    Attribute A              A2   1
8    (A, F)    Attribute A              A2   1
10   (A, G)    Attribute A              A2   1
22   (F, G)    Attribute A              A2   1
12   (B, C)    Attribute A              A1   2
16   (B, F)    Attribute A              A2   1
14   (B, D)    Attribute A              A1   2
21   (C, D)    Attribute B              B1   2
19   (B, G)    Attribute B              B3   1
17   (B, F)    Attribute B              B3   1
11   (A, G)    Attribute B              B3   1
13   (B, C)    Attribute B              B1   2
9    (A, F)    Attribute B              B3   1
7    (A, D)    Attribute B              B1   2
5    (A, C)    Attribute B              B1   2
3    (A, B)    Attribute B              B3   1
2    (A, B)    Attribute B              B1   2
15   (B, D)    Attribute B              B1   2
23   (F, G)    Attribute B              B3   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes a solution using `pivot_table`.

```
# df after "df.explode('Sequence Combs')"

attributes = ['Attribute A', 'Attribute B']

my_pivots = [df.pivot_table(index='Sequence Combs',
                            columns=attr,
                            aggfunc='count')['Sequence'] for attr in attributes]

final_df = (pd.concat(my_pivots, axis=1).melt(ignore_index=False)
                                        .dropna()
                                        .rename({'variable': 'Attribute Value',
                                                 'value': 'ID Count'},
                                                 axis=1))
```

This gives us a dataframe like this

```
               Attribute Value  ID Count
Sequence Combs                          
(A, B)                      A1       2.0
(A, C)                      A1       2.0
(A, D)                      A1       2.0
(B, C)                      A1       2.0
(B, D)                      A1       2.0
```

Note that it doesn't have the column `'Attribute Type'`. To fix this, you can simply run:

```
final_df['Attribute Type'] = 'Attribute ' + final_df['Attribute Value'].str[0]
```